# Flatlist is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have a flatlist but it is not scrollable, first i set the height of it's parent container to screen height then i learned that it was a mistake to do so and also i didn't use flex:1 on any container still i can't scroll down.

so how to set the height of the flatlist to cover the entire screen and still be scrollable

```js
 return(
      <LinearGradient  style={DocumentStyle.box}
      colors={['#053f5c','#00b1b2',"#429ebd"]}>
      <DrawerIcon/>  
      
        {isEmpty ?
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={DocumentStyle.conditions}>
          <Icon style={{flex:.3,opacity:.3,fontSize:125,fontWeight:'bold'}} name="file-pdf-o" color="#666"/>
        </View>
        </View> 
          :
        <View>
        <DrawerIcon/> 
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={DocumentStyle.searchBar}>
                <Icon style={DocumentStyle.searchIconStyle} name="search" color="#666"/>
                <TextInput
                style={DocumentStyle.searchText}
                  value={search}
                  placeholder="Rechercher un fichier"
                  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                  onChangeText={(text)=>searchFile(text)}
                /> 
              </View>
              <View style={DocumentStyle.secondContainer}>
              <FlatList style={DocumentStyle.flatstyle}
              keyExtractor={(item)=>item['id']}
              data={filteredfile}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              onRefresh={()=>onRefresh()}
              refreshing={refresh}
              />
              
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
        }
  </LinearGradient>
    );
```

```js
import {StyleSheet,Dimensions} from 'react-native';



const width=Dimensions.get('window').width
const height=Dimensions.get('window').height


const DocumentStyle=StyleSheet.create({
    box: {
        width:width,
        height: height,
      },

   
     secondContainer:{
        backgroundColor:'white',
        
       
     },
    flatitem:{
    backgroundColor:"white",
     shadowColor:'#000',
     shadowOffset:{
        width:0,
        height:2,
    },
     shadowOpacity:0.25,
     elevation: 5,
     color:'#666',
     padding:10,
     flexDirection:'row',
     justifyContent:'space-between'
     
},

itemtext:{
flex:1,
fontSize:18,
color:'#666',
padding:10,
textAlign:'left'


},
pdf:{
fontSize:25,
padding:10,

},
ellipsis:{
    fontSize:20,
    paddingTop:15,
    color:'#17224d'

    
},
searchBar:{
    marginTop:60,
    borderWidth:0.5,
    alignSelf:'stretch',
    borderColor:'#17224d',
    borderRadius:15,
    padding:2,
    margin:10,
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:"#fff"

  
},

searchText:{
    
    
},
searchIconStyle:{
  alignSelf:'flex-start',
  fontSize:18,
  alignSelf:'auto',
  marginRight:10,
  marginLeft:10,
  opacity:0.5,
},
conditions:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    alignContent:'center',
},
conditionText:{
    color:'#666',
    fontSize:18
}

})
export default DocumentStyle
```

Answer (score 1):

Set flex:1 style to all parents of FlatList and also set contentContainerStyle to FlatList like below:

```
<FlatList contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
   ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be related to view hierarchy, your list is children of a `LinearGradient` component (to have a gradient background I suppose) and `LinearGradient` is blocking touch events to children views.

To prevent that, add `pointerEvents={"none"}` prop to `LinearGradient`.

Comment: i can't do that because i need to click on each item to access it, i also replaced the gradient with a simple view but i still can't scroll